# Error on dragging a form element when using Ninject

Tags: sitecore-forms, dependency-injection

I am getting below error when I drag a form element on form designer. I think it is because of dependency injection. I am using `ninject` DI in my application. Looking for help how to handle dependencies for Sitecore forms.

Here is **error**:

```
Exception: Ninject.ActivationException
Message: Error activating IListDataSourceDefinitionProvider
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
```

**Activation path**:

1. Injection of dependency `IListDataSourceDefinitionProvider` into parameter `listDataSourceDefinitionProvider` of constructor of type `FormFieldController`
2. Request for `FormFieldController`

**Suggestions**:

1. Ensure that you have defined a binding for IListDataSourceDefinitionProvider.
2. If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
3. Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
4. If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
5. If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

   ```
   Source: Ninject
    at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request, Boolean handleMissingBindings)
    at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator2.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
    at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
    at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)
    at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
    at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request, Boolean handleMissingBindings)
    at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, IParameter[] parameters)
    at Cerner.IoC.Factories.NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   ```